# statically and dynamically linking the same library with different versions

Tags: opencv, c++11, cmake, arm, cross-compiling

I have a forked version of OpenCV (v2.4.8) compiled without FFMPEG as statically linked library (libopencv_core.a, libopencv_highgui.a etc) with some custom changes, I link that against my library say libsdk.so.

I am currently building sample apps over libsdk.so, these custom apps use OpenCV's highgui and core from (ap-get)package manager directly (v2.4.9 or v3.3) for opening camera and getting frames from video.

My sample application processes a video and then throws a segfault,

> 0x0000007fb20ca770 in av_malloc () from
>   /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libavutil-ffmpeg.so.54

I am using CMake to compile these libraries, I think this might be due to a symbol not getting resolved when the destructor is being called. Are there any tools to figure out what could be exactly happening. When I link the sample app to the custom-compiled opencv they work okay. This approach works on linux ubuntu x86_64, but not arm64(cross-compiled)

EDIT: I am writing this to get suggestions and feedback on what might be the issue here, currently the sample app freezes when it tries to deallocate memory. This sample app is written in C++11.

Comment: you are expecting them to link together and work?

Comment: yes, this approach works on linux x86_64, I think something might be specific to arm, maybe? the video-streaming screen freezes and then I have to send a kill signal to exit the app. I want the app to exit gracefully and without a core-dump.

Comment: I wouldnt assume this to work anywhere.  Maybe just lucky on x86?  What compiler (and linker) and version were used for building each of these?

Comment: @old_timer can I link two versions of same library one statically linked and other dynamically linked?

Comment: Compiler is same for both x86_64 and aarch64 its gcc-5, the linker is (GNU libc) 2.17 for aarch64  and (Ubuntu GLIBC 2.23-0ubuntu9) 2.23 for x86_64. EDIT : I tested on v2.23 for aarch64 and still have the same issue